# Hadoop and Eclipse environment

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

Trying to configure Eclipse and Hadoop, following [this site](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment).

I successfully ran:

```
git clone git://git.apache.org/hadoop-common.git
```

Now I get a failure on:

```
mvn install -DskipTests

[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [6.688s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... FAILURE [1.548s]
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (create-testdirs) on project hadoop-project: Error executing ant tasks: /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-common/hadoop-project/target/antrun/build-main.xml (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
```

The reason being I don't have a "target" folder in `.../hadoop-project`. My /hadoop-project folder contains only a "src" folder and that's it.

So it appears that folder was not established. Any ideas? Here is the environment:

```
Ubuntu 12.1
Hadoop 1.0.4
Maven 3.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The [site](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment) mentioned in the query is for development **of** Hadoop and not for developing applications **using** Hadoop. There is a difference between the two.

Here are the [instructions](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/10/debugging-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in.html) for for developing/debugging MapReduce programs in Eclipse. Note that the procedure applies for  Linux OS only.